# Maps solo muestra el primer punto añadido

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tengo un mapa al que añado varios puntos (parece que correctamente) pero el mapa solo me muestra el primero...

Aqui [**un fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/7hrxrL6f/10/) que muestra el mal funcionamiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACLARACIONES**

- No hay errores
- He comentado la parte de ajax que recoge los datos y simulado la respuesta minimizada en una variable para hacer el fiddle, pero esa parte va bien
- Los datos se pasan correctamente y parece que el array de `markers[]` se llena correctamente

Alguien ve que està pasando?

Creía que al hacer la llamada ajax podia ser la asincronia de javascript para el array de markers, pero el fiddle falla igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un error en los datos que le estas pasando, más exactamente en la longitud:

```
var data = "NOM;ADREÇA;TELEFON;HORARI;WEB;BLOG;X;Y;TIPUS\n\r" +
  "2d2despuma SHOP;Carrer de la Manigua 6<br>08027 Barcelona;+34 654 24 15 81;;http://www.2d2dspuma.com/;;41.422483;2.17941715;2\n\r" +
  "Quatre Pedres;Carrer Lleo<br>Badalona;+34 93 384 01 36;;http://www.4pedres.cat/;;41.4381275;2.232936;1\n\r" +
  "2d2despuma BAR;Carrer de la Manigua 8<br>08027 Barcelona;+34 654 24 15 81;;http://www.2d2dspuma.com/;;41.422483;2.17941715;1"
```

Le estás incluyendo una coma (,) adicional: `2.179417,15`.

De hecho en los alert que pusiste se ve.

Comment: si es que... no deberia currar ni a primera ni a última hora, me pillan empanadas muy grandes `':)` suerte que os tengo como par de ojos extras `<3`